# Read XML file from HDFS to parse in Pyspark with lxml.etree

Tags: xml, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, lxml

I have written a parser in Python using lxml.etree and I am now trying to run said parser on a Hadoop cluster. When I run the function locally it works as expected, but I receive the following error when I try to apply it to a file on the cluster (I am executing the following in a Pyspark shell, python3)

```
xml_pathname = "hdfs://file_path/date_directory/example_one.xml"
xml_tree = etree.parse(xml_pathname)

OSError: Error reading file '/file_path/date_directory/example_one.xml': failed to load external entity 
"/file_path/date_directory/example_one.xml"
```

I can see the file when I run `hdfs dfs -ls /file_path/date_directory/example_one.xml` in the terminal.

Two areas where I'd appreciate help -

1. How do I load XML files into the lxml.etree.parse() method from a cluster using Pyspark?
2. How can I best scale this up to run effectively on Spark? I would like to parse millions of XML files on the cluster using my Python parser--would the below modification work, or is there a better way to parralelize and run the parser at scale? Generally, how should I be setting the parameters in my spark configuration for optimal results (high number of executors, more than one driver, etc.)?

```
#Same as above but with wildcards to parse millions of XML files

xml_pathname = "hdfs://file_path/*/*.xml"
xml_tree = etree.parse(xml_pathname)
```

Been working on this for a while and would be so grateful any and all help. Appreciate y'all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. mapValues() function proved useful. Sark-configured XML parsers, such as the Pubmed parser, also presented useful boilerplate code, such as the following:

```
path_rdd = sc.parallelize(path_sample, numSlices=10000) # use only example path
    parse_results_rdd = path_rdd.map(lambda x: Row(file_name=os.path.basename(x), **pp.parse_pubmed_xml(x)))
    pubmed_oa_df = parse_results_rdd.toDF()
    pubmed_oa_df_sel = pubmed_oa_df[['full_title', 'abstract', 'doi',
                                     'file_name', 'pmc', 'pmid',
                                     'publication_year', 'publisher_id',
                                     'journal', 'subjects']]
    pubmed_oa_df_sel.write.parquet(os.path.join(save_dir, 'pubmed_oa_%s.parquet' % date_update_str),
                                   mode='overwrite')
```

https://github.com/titipata/pubmed_parser/blob/master/scripts/pubmed_oa_spark.py

2. Using fs.globStatus allowed for retrieval of multiple XML files within one subdirectory.